# container not sizing to full width of page

Tags: html, css

so what I have here is a little ui I'm building. looking at my html it's pretty simple, however I have some weird behavior going on. even though page container wraps the `aside` and `.main` element, it appears to be inserting itself into the grid. I want to the .main element into the center column of the `.page-container`'s grid. is there something im missing?

Anything you guys got would help.
thanks!

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  min-height:100vh;
}

label{
  margin:0.9em 0;
}

.page-container{
  display:grid;
  width:100vw;
  grid-template-columns:25% 50% 25%;
  grid-template-rows:100%;
  grid-template-areas:"margin main margin";
}

.main{
  grid-area:main;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-image:url("https://live.staticflickr.com/3771/11167360764_2512d790b3_z.jpg");
}

.controls{
  width:25%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  
  background-color:green;
  
  font-family:sans-serif;
  
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 3px 5px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 3px 5px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 10px 3px 5px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  
  word-break:break-word;
}
.controls-wrapper{
  margin:3em 5% 5% 1em;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="page-container">
  <aside class="controls">
      <form class="controls-wrapper">
        <label for="p_font_size">change paragraphs font size:</label>
        <br>
        <select name="" class="p_font_size">
          <option value="25pt">25pt</option>
          <option value="11pt">11pt</option>
        </select>
        
        
    </form>  
  </aside>
  <main class="main">
    <p>fsdanfdjsanfsdsafdsajansan</p>
  </main> 
</div>
```

Comment: There's a syntax error as you have `grid-template-areas` twice in `.page-container`. One without parameters and one with

Comment: i don't see that duplication in the code. where do you see another `grid-template-area`?

Answer (score -1):

The grid-template-rows property defines the height of each row. with changing that i think you can get your desire result for example :

```
   .page-container{
      display:grid;
      width:100vw;
      grid-template-columns:auto auto auto;
      grid-template-rows:100% 100% 100%;
      grid-template-areas:"margin main margin";
  }
```

grid-template-columns:25% 50% 25%  works fine too

hope i have understood you problem correctly